# The number of numbers on $[0,1]$ which can be written in the binary notion in two different ways is countable.

Tags: calculus, analysis, measure-theory, binary

I have done this question before but I can't seem to prove it this time. I think I concluded that the numbers that can be written in two different ways would be numbers with a finite notation and infinite notation at the same time.

But I'm having trouble formally putting this together, and proving it. Can anyone help out with this?

Comment: It would be the numbers which end with zero or one repeating. So...1000000... = ...0111111... This is a subset of the rationals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way a number in $[0,1]$ can be written two different ways is always as follows: it either has some number of digits, ending in a $1$, followed by an infinite number of $0$s; or it has those same digits, except the final $1$ is a $0$ and it is followed by an infinite number of $1$s instead.

To give an explicit bijection from $\mathbb N$ to such numbers, simply take any $n \in \mathbb N$, write it in binary (writing $0$ as the empty string), reverse it, prepend $0.$, and then pad it on the end with an infinite number of $0$s.

Edit: actually, this gives a bijection to $[0,1)$ instead. But of course a set with one element more than a countable set is still countable.

Comment: Could you give an example for number 15 say?

Comment: 15 is 1111 in binary. Reversing it gives 1111. Thus 15 is mapped to 0.111100000....

Comment: $15_{10} = 1111_2$, so we reverse it: $1111$, prepend $0.$: $0.1111$ and then pad it on the end with an infinite number of $0$s: $0.11110000000000\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

You are right that if a number has two representations, then one of them terminates at finite length. It is not difficult to list / count them all, thus proving that the set containing them is countable.

Start with the ones with $0$ bits after the decimal point before terminating. That's $0$ and $1$. Then the ones with one bit before terminating. That's just $0.1$. Then the ones with two bits. That's $0.01$ and $0.11$. Then three bits (four numbers here): $0.001, 0.011, 0.101,0.111$. And so on. In each step there are only finitely many of them (after the first hiccup, the number of numbers follows the powers of $2$).

So our list is countable, and every terminating number is counted, since we take all numbers of any given length before moving on to the next length.